# Use php functions in Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, md5, sqlsrv

So I have a GameAcc model with the following values inside it:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'AccountName', 'AccountLevelCode', 'SecondAuthFailCount', 'SecondAuthCode', 'SecondAuthLockFlag', 'CharacterCreateLimit', 'CharacterMaxCount', 'RegisterDate', 'PublisherCode', 'NxLoginPwd',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
```

When someone registers on my website, a GameAcc::create query is executed alongside a regular User::create. It looks something like this:

```
// Create the user
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
    ]);

    // Create the game account
    GameAcc::create([
      'AccountName' => $request->input('name'),
      'AccountLevelCode' => 0,
      'SecondAuthFailCount' => 0,
      'SecondAuthCode' => 1,
      'SecondAuthLockFlag' => 'false',
      'CharacterCreateLimit' => 10,
      'CharacterMaxCount' => 8,
      'RegisterDate' => Carbon::now(),
      'PublisherCode' => 0,
      'NxLoginPwd' => $request->input('password')
    ]);
```

Now, the GameAcc goes into an sqlsrv database while the User info goes into a regular mysql database. As you can see, `NxLoginPwd` isn't using bcrypt because the program reading from the sqlsrv needs the password to be hashed with MD5, so bcrypt is a no go.

What I'd need it to do ideally is something like:

```
GameAcc::create([
  'AccountName' => $request->input('name'),
  'AccountLevelCode' => 0,
  'SecondAuthFailCount' => 0,
  'SecondAuthCode' => 1,
  'SecondAuthLockFlag' => 'false',
  'CharacterCreateLimit' => 10,
  'CharacterMaxCount' => 8,
  'RegisterDate' => Carbon::now(),
  'PublisherCode' => 0,
  'NxLoginPwd' => strtoupper(md5($request->input('password')))
]);
```

But I know this doesn't work. So what options do I have to keep using bcrypt with User::create but use md5 with GameAcc::create?

I have looked at Eloquent mutators but it doesn't seem like that would help in this case.

Comment: What do u mean this isn't possible

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have at the moment? It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was erroring out because of DebugBar for some reason. Guess this actually works!